# How to add a toggle navigation menu button in Foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Foundation and I have read the documentation on its site and then I designed the navigation of my site like this:

```
<div class="top-bar BHoma">
            <div class="top-bar-left title-bar-left">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-text"><img src="img/text-logo.png" width="100"  height="50" title="شرکت طراحی، برنامه نویسی و بازاریابی دانوپ"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right title-bar-right">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So Basically I have added the correct classes attributes and it is also responsive but the problem is it does not show any kind of toggle menu button for small devices. I mean it only show menu links all together rather that displaying them in a something like `navbar-collapse` option in Bootstrap! So is there any way to add a menu toggle button with Foundation or it just ends like this ?

You can also check my entire website that I'm developing by clicking this [link](http://danoup.com).

Comment: Have you looked in to the `data-toggle` attribute. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#responsive-toggle

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the data-toggle directives found on the "Advanced Layout" section of http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-title">
    <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    </span>
    <strong>Site Title</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="responsive-menu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
          <a href="#">One</a>
          <ul class="menu vertical">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```